# The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id,password]

Tags: android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have log in app with pre populated database (ROOM).
When i'm logging in I need to check email and password in database then after that if email and password are correct, show final fragment. But i have error which is higher.

I was searching but nothing helps me.

---

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.continuebutton.setOnClickListener {
        if(binding.EmailSpace.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Поле пустое введите email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(binding.PasswordSpace.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Поле пустое введите пароль",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
       if(binding.PasswordSpace.length() <8){
           Toast.makeText(context,"Пароль слишком короткий",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }
        val espace = binding.EmailSpace.text.toString()
        val pspace = binding.EmailSpace.text.toString()
        if(espace.isNotEmpty() && pspace.isNotEmpty()){
            check(espace == "admin@gmail.com")
            check(pspace == "12345678")
            scope.launch {
            db.getDAO().findbyEmail(espace)
                db.getDAO().findbypassword((pspace))
            }
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_lastfragment)
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Данные введены не верно",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        }
    }
}
```

This is a fragment in which i'm checking edittexts for empty.

---

AdminDatabaseclass

```
import Room.DAO.DAO
import Room.Repository.Admindata
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database (entities = [Admindata::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)
abstract class AdminDatabase:RoomDatabase(){
abstract fun getDAO(): DAO
companion object{
    fun getadminDB(context: Context):AdminDatabase{
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,AdminDatabase::class.java,"admindb").createFromAsset("SQLDB/dbforpetproject.db").build()
    }
}
```

---

DAO

```
@Dao
interface DAO {
  @Query("select email from admindb where email = :email")
  suspend fun findbyEmail(email:String) : Admindata
  @Query("select password from admindb  where password = :password")
  suspend fun findbypassword(password:String) : Admindata

}
```

---

Admindata

```
@Entity(tableName= "admindb")
data class Admindata(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:Int = 1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "email")
    val email:String = "admin@gmail.com",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    val password :String = "12345678"
)
```

Error after launching how it looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nWhs.png)

---

Another one screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPn3A.png)

Comment: Do you have the email and password columns in the dbforpetproject.db file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use

```
@Dao
interface DAO {
  @Query("select * from admindb where email = :email")
  suspend fun findbyEmail(email:String) : Admindata
  @Query("select * from admindb  where password = :password")
  suspend fun findbypassword(password:String) : Admindata

}
```

Then the Admindata returned will have all the values from the database rather than just the email (`findbyEmail`) or the password (`findbyPassword`).

The `*` represents all columns, which is the equivalent of `SELECT id, email, password FROM admindb ....`